# Swiftmailer sending multiple emails hours apart

Tags: php, swiftmailer

So we use swiftmailer as part of "claim this business" procedure for our directory site. Basically it sends an email to the email address on file to verify ownership of the business when a user clicks on "Claim this business".

The problem is it sends it the first time fine, no issues, but then hours later another copy of the same email will show up again and then another a few hours later again. Can some one take a look and see if it is a problem with our script or if we have another issue going on.

here is the code, I am omitting where we set `$htmlEmail` and `$textEmail` for space purposes, but obviously they are set.

```
$getVar = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql = "SELECT email FROM auctioneer WHERE id = ?";
require('includes/db_connect.php');
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$getVar);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($email);
$stmt->fetch();

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.*****.com', 25)
->setUsername('sales@****.com')
->setPassword('******')
);

$textemail = 'blah blah blah';

$htmlemail = 'blah blah blah';


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('Auctioneer Directory Listing Claim');
$message->setFrom(array('sales@****.com' => '****'));
$message->setBody($textemail);
$message->addPart($htmlemail, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($email);

$mailer->send($message);

?>
```

Comment: sounds more like an issue with the mail server, check its logs

Comment: you sure there isn't a *ghost* cron happening? or a MySQL trigger? or a bot's sniffing your site and they're the "ghost cron". No idea.

Comment: what do you think @Dagon - goblins? ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- HobGoblins

Comment: No, we figured it out! Talk about a BIG mistake see answer below!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was pretty simple and a HUGE mistake on our part. But for those who ever run into something like this again it went something like this...

When we linked to the verify script, we didn't add `rel="nofollow"` to the link. You can probably guess what happened next. Yep, Google bot came along and tried to spider the link and an email was sent every time they hit the link...

**And that folks is how you tick off all 3400 people that are listed in your business directory!** ARGH!!!!!